# Proper usage of parallel streams in Java

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing, java-stream, forkjoinpool

I'm experimenting with parallel streams in Java and for that I've the following code for calculating number of primes before `n`.

Basically I'm having 2 methods

- `calNumberOfPrimes(long n)` - 4 different variants
- `isPrime(long n)` - 2 different variants

Actually I'm having 2 different variants of each of the above method, one variant that uses parallel streams and other variant that don't use parallel streams.

```java
    // itself uses parallel stream and calls parallel variant isPrime
    private static long calNumberOfPrimesPP(long n) {
        return LongStream
                .rangeClosed(2, n)
                .parallel()
                .filter(i -> isPrimeParallel(i))
                .count();
    }

    // itself uses parallel stream and calls non-parallel variant isPrime
    private static long calNumberOfPrimesPNP(long n) {
        return LongStream
                .rangeClosed(2, n)
                .parallel()
                .filter(i -> isPrimeNonParallel(i))
                .count();
    }

    // itself uses non-parallel stream and calls parallel variant isPrime
    private static long calNumberOfPrimesNPP(long n) {
        return LongStream
                .rangeClosed(2, n)
                .filter(i -> isPrimeParallel(i))
                .count();
    }

    // itself uses non-parallel stream and calls non-parallel variant isPrime
    private static long calNumberOfPrimesNPNP(long n) {
        return LongStream
                .rangeClosed(2, n)
                .filter(i -> isPrimeNonParallel(i))
                .count();
    }
    // uses parallel stream
    private static boolean isPrimeParallel(long n) {
        return LongStream
                .rangeClosed(2, (long) Math.sqrt(n))
                .parallel()
                .noneMatch(i -> n % i == 0);
    }

    // uses non-parallel stream
    private static boolean isPrimeNonParallel(long n) {
        return LongStream
                .rangeClosed(2, (long) Math.sqrt(n))
                .noneMatch(i -> n % i == 0);
    }
```

I'm trying to reason out which amongst `calNumberOfPrimesPP`, `calNumberOfPrimesPNP`, `calNumberOfPrimesNPP` and `calNumberOfPrimesNPNP` is the best in terms of proper usage of parallel streams with efficiency and why it is the best.

I tried to time all these 4 methods in 50 times and took the average using the following code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int iterations = 50;
        int n = 1000000;
        double pp, pnp, npp, npnp;
        pp = pnp = npp = npnp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            Callable<Long> runner1 = () -> calNumberOfPrimesPP(n);
            Callable<Long> runner2 = () -> calNumberOfPrimesPNP(n);
            Callable<Long> runner3 = () -> calNumberOfPrimesNPP(n);
            Callable<Long> runner4 = () -> calNumberOfPrimesNPNP(n);

            pp += TimeIt.timeIt(runner1);
            pnp += TimeIt.timeIt(runner2);
            npp += TimeIt.timeIt(runner3);
            npnp += TimeIt.timeIt(runner4);
        }
        System.out.println("___________final results___________");
        System.out.println("avg PP = " + pp / iterations);
        System.out.println("avg PNP = " + pnp / iterations);
        System.out.println("avg NPP = " + npp / iterations);
        System.out.println("avg NPNP = " + npnp / iterations);
    }
```

`TimeIt.timeIt` simply returns the execution time in milli-seconds. I got the following output:

```sh
___________final results___________
avg PP = 2364.51336366
avg PNP = 265.27284506
avg NPP = 11424.194316620002
avg NPNP = 1138.15516624
```

Now I'm trying to reason about the above execution times:

- The `PP` variant is not as fast as `PNP` variant because all parallel streams use common fork-join thread pool and if we submit a long-running task, we are effectively blocking all threads in the pool.
- But the above argument should also work for `NPP` variant and so the `NPP` variant should also be approximately as fast as the `PNP` variant. (But this is not the case, `NPP` variant is the worst in terms of time taken). Can someone please explain the reason behind this?

My questions:

- Is my reasoning correct for the small running time of `PNP` variant?
- Am I missing something?
- Why `NPP` variant is the worst (in terms of running time)?

How `TimeIt` is measuring time:

```java
class TimeIt {
    private TimeIt() {
    }

    /**
     * returns the time to execute the Callable in milliseconds
     */
    public static <T> double timeIt(Callable<T> callable) throws Exception {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(callable.call());
        return (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1.0e6;
    }
}
```

PS: I understand that this is not the best method to count the number of primes.  [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and other more sophisticated methods exists to do that. But by this example I just want to understand the behaviour of parallel streams and when to use them.

Comment: If you do microbenchmarks, you should use [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). Even if you do not use JMH, always make some burnin iterations for the HotspotVM to do its black JIT-magic.

Comment: @Turing85 yes I understand the importance of JMH. But here for this simple case I think that I want to concentrate more on what streams are doing under the hood and how to properly use parallel streams. JMH was my next step :)

Comment: JMH should always be the first step. As I said: the HotspotVM does unpredictable things. Without a proper burnin, your performance measurements are of no apparent value.

Comment: Sidequestion: how does `TimeIt` measure time? Does it use [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())? If not, rewrite it or ditch it.

Comment: Yes, it is using `System.nanoTime()`. I've updated the question to add the definition of `TimeIt`

Comment: there are many flaws with your tests, the problem with this kind of set-up is that you might have a false impression of reality, meaning those numbers you get could be so un-real that it is better to not look at them, at all.

Comment: @Eugene are you suggesting me to benchmark it using JMH?

Comment: JMH would be a good idea to begin with, but that is *itself* a tool you use and like any tool - it's very easy to use not for what it was designed for. My point is micro-benchmark is complicated, don't just assume numbers.

Comment: @Eugene okay, so what are you suggesting? If I don't benchmark it and I want to know which of the 4 methods is best to use, then how will I get to know which one to use? Are you specifically pointing to the above tests that they are not good? (I'm just a beginner and want to learn more that what should we do in such situations). I think you are suggesting to micro-benchmark it in a proper way.

Comment: you are saying this yourself - being a begginer, this is not where you start understanding this to begin with. If you really want to understand which of the methods is faster and why - I would start with `JMH` samples, this was my suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, it is clear, why NPP is so slow.

Arrange your resulting numbers in a table:

```
       |    _P    |   _NP
-------+----------+---------
  P_   |   2364   |   265
-------+----------+---------
  NP_  |  11424   |  1138
-------+----------+---------
```

So you see that it is always faster when the outer stream is parallel. This is because there is much work to be done in the stream. So the additional overhead for handling the parallel stream is low compared to the work to be done.

You see also that it is always faster when the inner stream is not parallel. `isPrimeNonParallel` is faster than `isPrimeParallel`. This is because there is not much work to be done in the stream. In most cases it is clear after a few steps that the number is not prime. Half of the numbers are even (only one step). The additional overhead for handling the parallel stream is high compared to the work to be done.

Comment: Your answer explains it well. Actually its the overhead of the parallel stream that should be considered. If you can get the result fairly quickly, then parallel streams might not be a good candidate. Thanks for the answer. I think it nailed it. :) I think my reasoning about the common fork-join pool for parallel stream is correct but it's not an influencing factor here.

Comment: @LavishKothari Yes, I think so. It also does not give you more parallelism, if there are already "enough" threads in the outer stream.